# Remove parent element and all children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a table, and every time the button gets submitted it adds a row to the table with 4 columns, I place a delete button in each row. My purpose is to be able to delete the entire row, but when I press it it only deletes the button. How can I delete the entire row?

```
$(this).parent().remove()
```

I tried this but it doesn't work, the td is directly within the tr so it should access the tr and delete it but the row still exists.

Comment: Show us more code. But I suspect you added that on the click event of the button. If so, the button's parent is the TD, which is getting removed, right?

Comment: correct, I found the issue just me not realizing i placed it within a td also...dumb mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to select the closest `tr` element, not the immediate parent. Without seeing your event binding, I'd guess that `$(this)` is the button, and that `$(this).parent()` is the `<td>`. Instead you should try:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Or, if you can guarantee a specific hierarchy of `tr>td>button`, then you could use:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```

I **strongly discourage** using the latter format, as it is tightly coupled to the structure of the HTML. If your HTML starts out as:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <button>Example</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and later changes to:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <button>Example</button>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

using `closest('tr')` will continue to work, but using `parent().parent()` will break.

---

Relating to your secondary issue of not having events fired. If you're binding events with `$('.foo button').click(removeRow);` (where `.foo` matches the `table` element), the events won't apply to newly created `button` elements. Instead you should be using the event-delegation form of `on` (or simply `delegate` if you're using an older version of jQuery):

```
$('.foo').on('click', 'button', removeRow);
```

This would store the event binding on the `table` element, and when the callback gets called, it would check to see if the element that triggered the specified event matches the selector specified in the second argument (in this case `'button'`) if it matches, it triggers the specified handler (in this case `removeRow`) in with the matched element as the context (within the handler, `this` would still point to a `button` element).

Comment: AHH I'm an idiot ty soo much this makes so much sense. And yes id rather use closest anyways its a lot safer.

Comment: ok just did some tests and it still doesn't seem to be working im using $(this).closest('tr').remove(); it looks like <tr> <td> </td> <td> </td> <td> <button> </button> </td> </tr> and it doesnt work

Comment: @Jupiter, are you certain that the event callback is being fired at all? Have you checked the debug console for possible errors (such as tyops)?

Comment: I am sure its working cause the button gets deleted itself, but the other columns remain intact.

Comment: @Jupiter, it sounds like you need to use a delegated event so that the event binding affects buttons in newly created rows. You'd want to delegate the event on the `<table>` or `<tbody>`.

Comment: So what happens, is when they press submit, i create a new row with 4 columns and the delete button is placed in the 4th column, then i have when the delete button is pushed to remove the closest tr, so it should remove the entire row no?

Comment: @Jupiter, removing the `tr` element will remove all of its children as well. It won't matter which column it's in.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your code looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column</td>
        <td><button></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, your `$(this).parent()` is the `<td>`, not the `<tr>`.  You need another `parent()`:

```
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
```